# How do you remove the replied/forwarded indicator from a message in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, forwarding, reply

In Outlook, when viewing an email that you have either replied to or forwarded in the past, it will say either "You replied to this message on DATE/TIME" (along with the icon showing a purple arrow pointing to the left) or "You forwarded this message on DATE/TIME" (along with the icon showing a blue arrow pointing to the right).  How do you remove that replied/forwarded indicator?

I came across a method in the past that worked.  It involved exporting the message, deleting it, and then reimporting it into your Inbox.  But I just tried that and I still see the indicator, so I must be missing a step.  I'm using Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy with VBA macro like this:

```vb
Sub ClearLastVerb()
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Item In ActiveExplorer.Selection
        Item.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10800003", -1
        Item.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003", 0
        Item.Save
    Next
End Sub
```

Just add this macro to your Outlook and after that you can place the button that will clear icon and last verb executed for the selected messages.

Comment: I created the macro, but when I try to run it I get a Microsoft Visual Basic dialog box that says "Run-time error '440': The operation failed."  When I press Debug it goes to the line that sets the property to 0.

Comment: This is werid... It works flawless in my test lab on Outlook 2007/2010/2013/2016. What type of account do you use in Outlook (Exchange/POP3/IMAP/...)?

Comment: It is an Exchange account.

Comment: Ok, try to add the "On Error Resume Next" line as shown in the script above.

Comment: That works to change the icon from the purple/blue arrow back to the regular envelope icon.  But it doesn't remove the "You replied to/forwarded this message on..."

Comment: Because for some reason th second "SetProperty" fails. Not sure what's going on here, it just works for me. Can you try it on other mailboxes?

Comment: I tried it on messages in the Inbox and also in Sent Items and got the same result.  Is that what you mean by other mailboxes?

Comment: No, I mean mailboxes of other users.

Comment: I don't have permission to do that.

Comment: Is the SetProperty trying to work on an item in the message list?  Maybe that's why the first SetProperty works, but not the second one (since the "You replied to/forwarded" text isn't in the message list but in the message pane)?

Comment: Unlikely. But you can try to select multiple messages and run the macro.